# Middle Div will not sit center of other divs

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to create my `header`. Which includes a Logo (left), Banner (center) and NavBar (Right). I can get them level with each other but cannot get the banner to sit perfectly central of the page.

The banner is pushed over towards the right, sitting approximately `70%` of the way across the screen.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

```css
#header1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: url(content/structure/fmabannerbehind.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
#logo {
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#logo img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
#banner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#banner img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
#menu1 {
  margin-right: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="header1">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="http://www.fmarchived.com">
      <img src="/content/structure/logo3.jpg" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="banner">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="/content/structure/fmabanneronly.jpg" alt="banner">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1">
    <div class="child2menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/fmarchived/">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/fmarchived">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOA0NFV-DuoqCRFT3YzBzRg">Youtube</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the 'absolute position' from #banner ..

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

> Perhaps I should have explained better, I want the banner to be center
>   of the entire page, regardless of what the other divs are doing

Then add `position:relative` to `#header1` and `position:absolute` +  `display: inline-table;` `position:absolute;` `left:0;` `right:0;`
  `margin:auto;` to `#banner` in  **both snippets**

#### Option#1 - using CSS flexbox

Using `justify-content: space-between` from `flexbox` you can do this, and simplify a lot your code

---

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0
}
#header1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative
}
#header1 > div {
  border: solid red
}
img {
  vertical-align: bottom
}
#banner {
  display: inline-table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header1">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="http://www.fmarchived.com">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/100" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="banner">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="banner">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1">
    <div class="child2menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/fmarchived/">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/fmarchived">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOA0NFV-DuoqCRFT3YzBzRg">Youtube</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Option#2 - using your current code

Change `position:absolute` from `#header1` to `relative` to remove scrollbars

---

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0
}
#header1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: url(content/structure/fmabannerbehind.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
#header1 > div {
  border: 3px solid red
}
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align:bottom
}
#logo {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#banner {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-table;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;

    
}
#menu1 {
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header1">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="http://www.fmarchived.com">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="banner">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="banner">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1">
    <div class="child2menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/fmarchived/">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/fmarchived">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOA0NFV-DuoqCRFT3YzBzRg">Youtube</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I run your code snipper and noticed that the middle picture is not actually central. Its slightly over to the right

Comment: @MattDempsey it is centered between both left/right  divs.

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained better, I want the banner to be center of the entire page, regardless of what the other divs are doing

Comment: running your snippet shows the middle div sitting next to left div, not in the middle of the screen, this also happened to me after I tried it.

Comment: either you want centered related to "screen" or you want centered related to the divs. It appears that you want the best of the 2 worlds

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position: absolute` property from the #banner div. If the #banner div needs to be absolutely positioned for some reason, you can center it by giving it a width and appropriate`left` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the position absolute and it will align to the center.

```
#banner {
  /*position:absolute;*/
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use coordonates and margin: auto; to center your boxe if tou use absolute . but you need to reset display .

```
#banner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: table;/* shrinks on content */
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: 0 auto;/* will center in between coordonates if boxe smaller */
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

run code snippet bellow:

```css
#header1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: url(content/structure/fmabannerbehind.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,gray 50%, lightgray 50%);
}
#logo {
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#logo img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
#banner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#banner img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
#menu1 {
  margin-right: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="header1">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="http://www.fmarchived.com">
      <img src="/content/structure/logo3.jpg" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="banner">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="/content/structure/fmabanneronly.jpg" alt="banner">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1">
    <div class="child2menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/fmarchived/">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/fmarchived">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOA0NFV-DuoqCRFT3YzBzRg">Youtube</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```